# Laravel Inner page Not loading -- htaccess issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I am trying to develop a laravel web application in my new mac.

I configured built in php, apche, mysql in mac and working all fine.

Installed new laravel and make a new route for it and try to run it showing not found error.

I tried below steps.

1. checked my httpd.conf file for occurence of

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module     libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
   LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
   ```
2. Then:

   ```
   DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites"
   <Directory "/Users/username/Sites">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

All are fine. But...

How to solve this. Thanks..

Comment: Suggested way to run Laravel is by using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead)

Answer (score 0):

The best resource is here:
https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two
If you follow the instructions on a mac, it will all work fine.

Comment: hi, is there any other possibility without using homesta=ead. i think its too hard to understand. right ?

Comment: This may help. It is  with using mamp. If you follow the instructions, you should be able to start. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2jUTeiymY4

Comment: I tried mamp but i got many issues with extensions and many ... how to possible with php,mysql, apache...

Comment: You need to have some of the extensions, like mcrypt, in order to use Laravel. That video shows step by step what to do in order to resolve those problems and make it work. From what I see, you want an "out of the box" option. This seems to be one of the closest things you can get.

Comment: but what is the problem with build in php,apache, mysql ?

Comment: You need to make sure that you install yourself all the needed dependencies. Make sure you have all PHP extensions needed by Laravel. Using a package like mamp, or some other similar one, will reduce your overhead, because other people have already solved the problems you will encounter if you try to make it work on your own. It is easier to use a standard solution, that is documented, because you will find all the help you need to make it work with a simple search on youtube, google or anywhere else. Asking for help will also give you better chance to get help if you use a standard solution.

Comment: Just Ignore that. i tried homestead and its not getting output. showing cconnection timed out...